# The Lebesgue point theorem for locally average function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $Q=(0,1)\times(0,1)\subset \mathbb R^2$ and $u\in L^\infty(Q)$ be given. Define, for $N\in\mathbb N$, that a small cube
$$
Q_{N}(i,j):=(i/N,(i+1)/N)\times (j/N,(j+1)/N)
$$
where $0\leq i,j<N$. Hence, $Q=\bigcup_{0\leq i,j<N}Q_N(i,j)$ and each $Q_N$ are mutually disjoint.

My question: do we have 
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{0\leq i,j<N}\left\|u-\frac{1}{|Q_N(i,j)|}\int_{Q_{N}(i,j)}u(y)dy\right\|_{L^2(Q_N(i,j))}=0
$$
hold?

At the beginning I though this is just an easy conclusion from Lebesgue point theorem, but later I realize it may not be that easy...

Any help is really welcome!

Comment: Isn't it just the Lebesgue point theorem + dominated convergence theorem ? Also small detail but if the $Q_N(i,j)$ are open their union is not $Q$, but it's nots a problem since their boundary has zero measure.

Comment: @Renart can you write it as an answer?

Comment: Ok my first idea about Lebesgue point theorem was wrong. I posted an answer based on lusin's theorem. However believe that lebesgue point theorem is true if you replace the average on a ball centered on $x$ by a measurable shape included in the ball such that the ratio of the measures of the shapes and the balls are greater than some $\varepsilon$. Then you would get convergence almost everywhere and boundeness is given by the fact that $f$ is $L^\infty$, thus dominated convergence theorem would apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this proof using lusin's theorem works. I still think there is a proof using a variation of Lebesgue point theorem and dominated convergence, see my comment.

Let say we're in $[0;1]$ instead of $[0;1]^2$, it doesn't change the proof much and it simplify the notations.

First your result is true if $f$ is continuous, by the dominated convergence theorem for example. Now take a function $f$ in $L^\infty[0;1]$, let's call $f_n$ the sequence of local average approximation of $f$ you use in your question. Without lost of generality assume that $|f(x)|\leq M$ **everywhere** (and not only almost everywhere). We use Lusin's theorem : for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a compact $K$ and a continuous function $g$ such that $g_{|K}=f_{|K}$, $\|g\|_\infty\leq M$ and such that $\lambda(K)=1-\varepsilon$. We also call $g_n$ the sequence of local average approximations of $g$, one has that $g_n\to g$ in $L^2[0;1]$.

Now we use the so called "$3\varepsilon$ trick" :

$$\|f_n-f\|_2\leq \|f_n-g_n\|_2+\|g_n-g\|_2+\|g-f\|_2 $$

We have $||g-f||_2\leq 2\sqrt{\varepsilon} M$ and for $n$ large enough we also have $\|g_n-g\|_2\leq \varepsilon$. Now we evaluate the last term :

$$\|f_n-g_n\|_1=\int|f_n-g_n|d\lambda=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}}\left|n\int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}}f-g d\lambda\right|d\lambda$$$$\leq\sum_{k=1}^n n\int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}}\int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}}|f-g| d\lambda d\lambda=\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}}|f-g|d\lambda=\|f-g\|_1\leq 2\varepsilon M.$$

Since the $f_n-g_n$ are bounded by $2M$ uniformly in $n$ we have

$$\|f_n-g_n\|_2^2\leq 2M \|f_n-g_n\|_1\leq 4M^2\varepsilon$$ and thus $\|f_n-g_n\|_2\leq 2M\sqrt\varepsilon$

Combining all this we get that, for $n$ large enough, $\|f-f_n\|_2\leq 4M\sqrt\varepsilon +\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary this conclude the proof.

**Edit** here is the proof in the case where $f$ is continuous. Since the $f_n$ are all uniformly bounded by $M$ to apply dominated convergence we only need to show pointwise convergence of the $f_n$. Take $x\in [0;1]$ and $\varepsilon>0$. There is a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|< \varepsilon$. For every $n$ such that $1/n<\delta$ the number $x$ is contained in a $I_n=[k_n/n;(k_n+1)/n[$ interval and thus

$$f_n(x)=n\int_{I_n} f(x) dx\in[f(x)-\varepsilon;f(x)+\varepsilon] .$$

In other words $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon.$

Comment: Hi sorry for my late responding. Could you just expanding a little about how to conclude for the case $f$ is continuous by use dominated convergence? Then this should be a perfect answer.

Comment: @JumpJump I added the proof of the case $f$ continuous at the end of my post. Have you searched for the variation of lebesgue point theorem i was talking about ?